# Several installers on the same drive

Tags: linux, windows, installation, grub

i have 256gb usb ssd drive, and i want to put here partition for file storage, and at the same time windows installer, manjaro installer and ubuntu installer. is here a way that i can put here several installers to chose one from GRUB?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Is this an external or portable drive? Have you researched placing multiple installers on a single drive? What have you tried?